# How to set the "float" style using FluentHtml in MVCContrib

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, fluenthtml

I'm working in ASP.NET MVC 1.0 using MvcContrib FluentHtml version 1.0.

The following code doesn't work because `float` is a C# keyword.

```
<%= this.TextBox(m => m.Name).Styles(float => "left") %>
```

How do I define the "float" css style using the `Styles` method in FluentHtml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prefix the argument with an @.

```
<%= this.TextBox(m => m.Name).Styles(@float => "left") %>
```

When using the argument inside the lambda remember to keep verbatim escape the argument.

```
@float => @float.ToString()
```